# android project corrupted

Tags: android, eclipse

I've just edited one of the layout files in my project in eclipse, and something is corrupted in the activity classes, I got this error about importing my package

```
The import com.Android.mysmartrecipeassistant.R cannot be resolved
```

What can I do?

Comment: It usually means that your layout file has errors, anything underlined in red?

Comment: you have an error in your XML layout file, check it and then try Project->Clean in Eclipse.

Comment: no thing wrong in the layout files, the errors are all in the activities files, and any line that has R in it, is underlined in red, and it seems that those activities don't see my layout files and importing my own package doesn't work either..

Comment: I knew the problem, my R class is lost from my package under gen files, so can I restore it ?

Answer (score 2):

An alternate solution to this problem may be...

If you have installed a newer version of ADT, will stop creating the gen folder which includes R.java

The solution to this is to install new Android SDK build tools from the Android SDK Manager.

Sometimes this may help.

Answer (score 0):

First clean your project and see if there is any error in the XML files if not then check "gen" folder in your project if the name of the package there matches your package name. Most probably the error will be because of XML.

Answer (score 0):

In your  project **res** folder/sub-folder, you have put some file, whose name is not android standard thus you got the error. Just change the name of the file to acceptable one. It will go fine. common mistake like *my-file.xxx*, in this case use **my_file.xxx**.